# SQL Server: The bulk load failed. The column is too long in the data file for row 1, column 1

Tags: sql-server, bcp

Someone please help me here. Been looking at this for a couple of hours now but leading to nowhere.

I created a table in SQL Express 2008 R2 using the following script:

```
CREATE TABLE Features
(
ID int not null identity(1,1 ),
StopID varchar(10), 
Code int,
Name varchar(100),
Summary varchar(200),
Lat real,
Lon real,
street varchar(100),
city varchar(50),
region varchar(50),
postcode varchar(10),
country varchar(20),
zone_id varchar(20),
the_geom geography


 CONSTRAINT [PK_Features] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Then I created the following format file created against my database table using the bcp tool:

```
10.0
12
1       SQLCHAR             2       100     ","    2     StopID               Latin1_General_CI_AS
2       SQLINT              1       4       ","    3     Code                 ""
3       SQLCHAR             2       100     ","    4     Name                 Latin1_General_CI_AS
4       SQLCHAR             2       200     ","    5     Summary              Latin1_General_CI_AS
5       SQLFLT4             1       4       ","    6     Lat                  ""
6       SQLFLT4             1       4       ","    7     Lon                  ""
7       SQLCHAR             2       100     ","    8     street               Latin1_General_CI_AS
8       SQLCHAR             2       50      ","    9     city                 Latin1_General_CI_AS
9       SQLCHAR             2       50      ","    10    region               Latin1_General_CI_AS
10      SQLCHAR             2       10      ","    11    postcode             Latin1_General_CI_AS
11      SQLCHAR             2       20      ","    12    country              Latin1_General_CI_AS
12      SQLCHAR             2       20      "\r\n"    13    zone_id              Latin1_General_CI_AS
```

This file has been modified to remove the ID and the_geom fields as these are not in my data file.

Then I tried to bulk insert a 1 line csv with the following content:

```
a,8,S,,45.439869,-75.695839,,,,,,
```

and all I get:

```
Msg 4866, Level 16, State 7, Line 35
The bulk load failed. The column is too long in the data file for row 1, column 1. Verify that the field terminator and row terminator are specified correctly.
Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 35
The OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 35
Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".
```

Any pointers will help here as I cannot figure this one out.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Problem was caused by the default prefix length settings in my format file.  The data file I am importing from was not created using bcp so I had to set the prefix length of all the fields to 0 as follows:

```
0.0
12
1       SQLCHAR             0       100     ","    2     StopID               Latin1_General_CI_AS
2       SQLINT              0       4       ","    3     Code                 ""
3       SQLCHAR             0       100     ","    4     Name                 Latin1_General_CI_AS
4       SQLCHAR             0       200     ","    5     Summary              Latin1_General_CI_AS
5       SQLFLT4             0       4       ","    6     Lat                  ""
6       SQLFLT4             0       4       ","    7     Lon                  ""
7       SQLCHAR             0       100     ","    8     street               Latin1_General_CI_AS
8       SQLCHAR             0       50      ","    9     city                 Latin1_General_CI_AS
9       SQLCHAR             0       50      ","    10    region               Latin1_General_CI_AS
10      SQLCHAR             0       10      ","    11    postcode             Latin1_General_CI_AS
11      SQLCHAR             0       20      ","    12    country              Latin1_General_CI_AS
12      SQLCHAR             0       20      "\r\n"    13    zone_id              Latin1_General_CI_AS
```

With this change, the import was succesful.

Comment: Many years later... I have been wrestling with this for days, and this answer solved the issue for me.

Comment: @KlausNji: Were you able to bulk insert the file with just one row? I tried the same, but if the one (basically the row which is last row) has last column as empty, (just like in your file), it ignores that row completely. I haven't been able to find a solution to that.

Answer (score 9):

Try this,

```
ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0a'
```

Comment: Thanks Milan, that worked for me..  Where the commented values did not , ROWTERMINATOR = '0x0a' --'\o\r\n'

Answer (score 1):

i encountered this problem today, but only for specific ROWS with COLUMNS whose text value exceeds 8000 characters. Regardless if my FMT file was SQLCHAR 0 0 which indicated max, but somewhere along the pipeline, there is a max of 8000

I'm using AZURE SQL and trying to read CSVs in an Azure Blob container.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I had the same problem because a conflict between the expected format and actual format of the date field in my CSV.  I changed the date format in my CSV, and the it worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you are generating your format file useing `bcp` be aware of the -n and -c flags.

My problem was that i had the -n (native) flag specified while my data file was only compatible with the -c (character) flag.

**format file generation**
`bcp <DATABASE>.<SCHEMA>.<TABLE> format nul -t ; -T -c -S <IP> -f filename.fmt`
**data file generation**
`bcp "select * from table" queryout "filename.dat" -c -C 65001 -t ; -S <IP> -d <DATABASE> -T`
**bulk import**

```
BULK INSERT dbo.table 
FROM 'filename.dat'
WITH (FORMATFILE = 'filename.fmt');
```