# Bulk Insert column is too long

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert, bcp

I have a text file with fixed length data.  Here's my table:

```
create table myBulkInsert(
MaxData Varchar(Max)
)
```

x.fmt contains:

```
10.0
1
1       SQLCHAR             8       0       ""   1     MaxData                SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS
```

When I issue the following:

```
bulk insert myBulkInsert
from 'C:\inetpub\ftproot\TextFile.txt'
WITH (
    FORMATFILE = 'C:\inetpub\ftproot\Client.fmt'
);
```

I get:

> Msg 4866, Level 16, State 17, Line 1 The bulk load failed. The column
>   is too long in the data file for row 1, column 1. Verify that the
>   field terminator and row terminator are specified correctly. Msg 7399,
>   Level 16, State 1, Line 1 The OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server
>   "(null)" reported an error. The provider did not give any information
>   about the error. Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 1 Cannot fetch a
>   row from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".

What's odd is that I'm using Bulk Insert with a comma delimited text file and it works great, so I don't think it's a permissions error.

The reason why I just have it as 1 field with a max value is to simplify the example.
As soon as I get this 1 field working, I'll change the layout to include all the fields and their lengths.

Comment: In my experience, that's usually caused by a difference in the number of fields in the data file versus the server table. As a result, it's trying to load several fields worth of data into just one of the server table's fields, causing an overload.

Comment: I don't think that's it.  I'ved reduced the file down to two rows, 7 characters each and it's still not working.

Comment: I think this was the answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8513943/sql-server-the-bulk-load-failed-the-column-is-too-long-in-the-data-file-for-ro