# "The column is too long in the data file" while doing bulk insert from native data file

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, bulkinsert, sql-server-2014

I'm trying to copy all data in a table to another SQL server's identical empty table. I'm using a transfer file cause direct SQL-connection is not possible. For some reason the insert fails with this single table. I've used it successfully with many other tables. Any ideas what causes the issue or how to overcome it?

**Source:** Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (SP2) - 10.50.4321.0 (X64) 
    Jul  9 2014 15:59:57 
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
    Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1  (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (Hypervisor)

**Target:** Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.4100.1 (X64) 
    Apr 20 2015 17:29:27 
    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation
    Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.1  (Build 7601: Service Pack 1) (Hypervisor)

**Exported using command-line:**

```
bcp myDB.dbo.f_myTable out f_myTable -n -S 123.123.123.123 -U myUsername -P %passwd%
```

**Tried importing using T-SQL:**

```
BULK INSERT dbo.f_myTable FROM 'C:\f_myTable' WITH (DATAFILETYPE='native',keepidentity);
```

**Resulted in error:**

> Msg 4866, Level 16, State 4, Line 70
>       The bulk load failed. The column is too long in the data file for row 1, column 13. Verify that the field terminator and row terminator
>   are specified correctly.
>       Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 70
>       The OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
>       Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 70
>       Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".

**Here's what I've tried already with no luck:**

- Recreating the table in source using the script from source.
- Played with import options: KEEPIDENTITY, BATCHSIZE, MAXERRORS, KEEPNULLS
- Exported using the server's command line in addition to my local PC

Comment: Potentially the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8513943

Comment: Thanks, but I think my case is a bit different cause I'm using the native format instead of defining the format manually where a mistake might occur.

Comment: Make your life easy, generate a format file from the output and use it in the BULK INSERT statement.